# Is it possible to take a vite/vue3 app and transform it so that it is not reliant on any build tool?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-router4

I have a web application that was built in vue 3 and reliant upon vitejs as a build tool. I am now being asked to remove the vitejs build tool due to security reasons. Is this even possible? The app does have several .vue files within the traditional 'views' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I assume that you are running your app using Vite in a dev environment?
If so, you can always build the project and get a JS app (it will be located in a dist folder).
This JS app would work independently on any browser.

The command in Vite would be :
npm run build

Alternatively, you may even create a desktop app using Electron.js
This will turn your web based vue app into a desktop app.